# Is it possible to create an Isometric Video

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I am making a game, which is having a theater as room. However right now, it's only meant for simple "swf" shows. But i was wondering, if their is a requirement of a video, then is it possible to convert a plain video, to embed itself in an isometric environment. The video's dimensions would need to be skewed. Is it feasible ?

Comment: Not quite sure why this question has a vote to close, as it does "involve facts, references, or specific expertise" to answer. Maybe the person who voted could comment on there reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably rotate the video into position using the 3D API. Try using rotationX, rotationY, and rotationZ. Also you might need to adjust the camera to not draw perspective.

There are also a whole bunch of [AS3 isometric engines](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2010/02/23/11-flash-isometric-engines-you-can-use-in-your-games/) out there. Some of these might even support video.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use the `flash.geom.Matrix` class for this, because Isometric is different than 3D in that it maintains its size regardless of distance from the observer.

Have a look at the docs and you will find examples of how to skew an object.

[flash.geom.Matrix](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html)

Comment: Thanks, i will se that.
Please share if you have any idea with 3d, because i think, removing the perspective information would give the correct result

Comment: You can correct the scale issues with the camera setting, as I mentioned in my answer.